# Why is my bar chart in ggplot2 using different fonts on the x and y axis?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The stacked bar chart I've made using ggplot2 seems to be using slightly different fonts on each axis. The characters on the y axis seem to be slightly thinner and a slightly lighter shade of gray. I've tried explicitly setting the font size, color, and face, but that doesn't resolve the issue. I'm including a screenshot of my plot.
Here's my code:

```
ggplot(full, aes(fill=ind, y=values, x=ISIC.Year)) + 
    geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("#00CC33", "#FFFF33", "#FF0033")) + 
    theme(legend.position="none", axis.title.x=element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(),
         axis.title.y=element_blank(), panel.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color="black"), 
         panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
         text = element_text(family = "Optima", size = 12, colour = "black"), panel.ontop = TRUE)+ scale_x_continuous("ISIC.Year", labels = as.character(full$ISIC.Year), breaks = full$ISIC.Year) + 
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1,.25), labels = percent)
```

[image]

Comment: Try with `scale_x_continuous("ISIC.Year", breaks = unique(full$ISIC.Year))`. The issue is not different fonts. The issue is overplotting. Without using `unique()` each `Year` or tick is labelled multiple times which gives rise to the `bold` look.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not related to different fonts. The issue is overplotting. Using `scale_x_continuous(..., breaks = full$ISIC.Year)` each tick is labelled multiple times which gives rise to the bold look.

As an illustration of this issue consider this simple example based on `mtcars`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = mtcars$cyl)
```

[image]

One option to solve this issue would be use `scale_x_continuous("ISIC.Year", breaks = unique(full$ISIC.Year))`:

Note: Adding the additional `labels = as.character(full$ISIC.Year)` is not necessary. The `labels` argument is only required if you want to have labels for the ticks which are different from the values of the breaks.

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl)) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(mtcars$cyl))
```

[image]